Best method to identify layered clusters
The Problem
Hello everyone. I'm working with a dataset that has 15300 samples with 49 features each, equally distributed amongst three classes. I used TSNE to reduce the dimensions of the feature space to 2D to better visualize the distribution of the data and found something a little weird (for me, at least). The classes seem to be layered on top of each other.
Embbeded Data Distribution

Euclidean Distances

Cosine Similarity

I know the graphs are disgusting, sorry about that. Anyways, is there a clustering algorithm that can properly identify these classes? I've heard that spectral clustering methods are pretty good at identifying non-convex clusters, but their spacial and computational complexity is very high, which is not good because I'm limited to 16GB of RAM only. Is there an iterative method that approximates the solution provided by the traditional spectral clustering method (eigen decomposition of the graph laplacian)?

You need to say more about your samples and the 49 features. What are they? That would be a key clue to the high degree of overlap in the scatterplot, at least in two dimensions. A classic approach like hierarchical clustering would provide a chart like a dendogram which visualizes how the data is being split.

Hey, thanks for the response. The samples are LBP descriptors. I don't remember the exact parameters, but it's something close to 6 points and 50 radius. This dataset was used previously by my research advisor in a paper related to roughsets theory and boundary identification. Because the roughsets framework only deals with discrete data, the features were discretized. Also, the professor diminished the quality of the descriptors on purpose to force the existence of boundary. So maybe these are the reasons for the high degree of overlap: the descriptors suck, and the features were discretized.

My advisor asked me to try and find a graph related aproach to find boundary elements. But I'm working with this dataset for six months now, and it's a giant mess. Never seen something like it. I tried spectral clustering with RBF kernel and varying values for the gamma parameter. The normalized mutual info capped at 0.045. Distance just doesn't seems to be a discriminant metric for similarity at all

Sounds pretty crazy. Is there any way to recover the original, pre-discretized info? I understand that LBP uses categorical information but that is so procrustean as the loss of information due to discretizing is considerable. Wrt graph related approaches correspondence analysis is one such method especially intended for discrete data.

Please add new information as an edit to the post, and not only as a comment. Comments will be seen by few people ...
